# Creating a text/csv file from LibreOffice

Tags: csv, libreoffice, libreoffice-base

I am in the process of starting a project and i want to understand the best way to automate the creation of a text/CSV file containing the result of a request. And each time the database is updated, i want that file to be updated too. I'm using LibreOffice Base.

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: Yes, i have created a csv file from a request (but manually).

Comment: As @nathanBuckley has pointed out `base` is a query tool. The database and the software updating it may well reside on another machine, which is where you want to concentrate on creating the csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Hay,

LibreOffice Base is not going to help you in this case as it is just a GUI tool for querying a Connected DB.

I would look at getting your backend to append to a log/CSV file every time it receives a request and successfully obtains/manipulates data in the Database.